# Creating dynamic return based on date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, circular-dependency

I have a complex issue that I am hoping someone can assist in resolving.

In the attachment below, there are two tabs.

1. A list of currency trades made. For example I have used the GBP/USD currency market. But other than for purposes of this example, that is irrelevant. It could be any currency or stock. Each of these orders has a date and a time when the order was opened. For purposes of understanding, the trades shown are managed by a trading service.
2. A list of investors who have invested their money to the trading service. Each deposit has a time and date attached to it.

What I want to achieve is calculating and show the live balance of each investor depending on the trades they have been involved with. If their deposit has arrived after trade 8 has commenced, their funds would only take profit (or loss) from trades 9 and onwards, not 8 and before.

Additionally, I want to make a calculation as to each investors 'peak total'. This would show the maximum their balance has been historically.

Any help that can be provided would be highly appreciated.

LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13C3oRmrzH49biq9qSOV3smEIMgUeBFRZFMhWjpDGXWc/edit?usp=sharing